# Save messages sent from another user

Tags: linux, command-line

I am wondering if there is a way to save a message sent from another user using the `write` command on a linux machine.

Suppose I send another user a message by doing the following:

```
user1@linux:~$ write user2
hello
```

and on their end they receive the message as follows:

```
user2@linux:~$      
Message from user1@linux on pts/112 at 18:13 ...
hello
EOF

user2@linux:~$
```

How can user2 (the recipient of the message), save the message sent by user1? Ideally, the command would be entered after receiving the message not before. However, I am open to all suggestions including non-ideal ones.

Here is a list of some things I've tried:

1. Script

   - Entering script before the message is sent doesn't seem to work, it captures output from commands entered by user2 (ex. `echo 'hello'`) but it does not capture message sent by user 1
2. Screen

   - Using `screen` before receiving the message and then `hardcopy -h <filename>` has the similar issue of not saving the message
3. Logsave

   - I am currently experimenting with `logsave` but have not had any success

Ideally the solution to this issue would not involve acquiring external packages.

Thanks,

Comment: This seems like a problem that has already been solved, you probably want an irc server/slack or email. Why do you need to use `write` which is not really intended to send permanent messages. Really you probably want to set up a local mail server since it seems you are on the same machine.

Comment: @user1794469 I don't have the permissions to setup a mail server.

I'd also be interested in further documentation on how `write` works if anyone has it

Comment: `man write`? And the `man` pages it refers to.

Comment: @waltinator https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-write/